# Erro ao nao preencher os campos do programa

Tags: c

Criei um programa no VisualStudio que utiliza 4 TextBox, e quando não coloco nada nas 4 TextBox e depois clico no botão que soma o que há dentro das 4 TextBox o programa da erro, como posso substituir esse erro por uma mensagem do tipo "Preencha os campos antes de continuar" ?

Comment: Você colocou que É C. A resposta foi em VB.Net. Quem está errado?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode testar todos eles antes de fazer a operação:

```
if txt1.text="" or txt2.text = "" or txt3.text = "" or txt4.text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Preencha todos os campos!")
End If
```

Ou pode atribuir 0 para os textboxes que estiverem vazios:

```
if txt1.text= "" Then
    txt1.text = "0"
End If
' ....
```

Ou direto na comparação, converter para inteiros:

```
Dim resultado as integer = CInt(txt1.text) + CInt(txt2.text) '....
```

Comment: Você pode me explicar como funciona esses códigos ?
Só entendi que: se a TextBox1 for igual a "" ou TextBox2 for igual a "" vai aparecer a mensagem de preencha todos os campos.
só não entendi qual a função do "".
(sou iniciante)

Comment: Agora vi que sua dúvida é em C, ams a lógica é a mesma.

Se texbox1 = em branco OU textbox2 = em branco...etc, não faz o cálculo e exibe a mensagem para o usuário preencher todos, assim não gera erro.

A segunda alternativa é a mesma coisa, mas em vez de exibir mensagem, você mesmo vai preencher com "0" caso o texto daquele textbox esteja em branco e depois fazer a soma.

Já a terceira utilizar a conversão do .net "CInt", onde ele tenta converter o que está no campo para o inteiro, por isso nada = 0. 

A linguagem c deve ter algo similar caso queira essa resolução.

Comment: Sim, o "" significa que aquele textbox está vazio. Se ele digitar alguma coisa o programa entenderia como textbox1.text = "120". Como é um textbox, a ideia é que o que está ali é um texto e texto sempre é colocado entre aspas.

Comment: Muito obrigado :D